# Looking to do Opening Price of today minus Opening price of yesterday in R

Tags: r

I am trying to add a column to my data frame called TR that will include data calculated based on the Opening price of today minus the opening price of yesterday. Can someone help pls. It is very simple but the result is null.

```
library(quantmod)
myData <- new.env()
class(myData)
mySymbols <- c('AAPL','BABA')
startDate = Sys.Date()-180
endDate = Sys.Date()
getSymbols(mySymbols, env = myData, src = "yahoo", from = startDate, to = endDate)
head(myData$AAPL)
OpenPrice<-Op(myData$AAPL)
HighPrice<-Hi(myData$AAPL)
LowPrice<-Lo(myData$AAPL)
ClosePrice<-Cl(myData$AAPL)
Volume<-Vo(myData$AAPL)
n = nrow(myData$AAPL)
#TRAITEMENT MIDPOINT
MP = (HighPrice+LowPrice)/2
names(MP)[names(MP)=="AAPL.High"] <- "MP"
plot(MP)
chartSeries(MP,name="MidPoint in Local Currency")
head(MP)
NewDataSet <- data.frame(myData$AAPL,MP)
#TRAITEMENT TR
TR <- OpenPrice[2:n, 1]-OpenPrice[1:(n-1), 1]
head(TR)
```

Answer (score 0):

Before subtracting change the values into `numeric`.

```
TR <- as.numeric(OpenPrice[2:n, 1])-as.numeric(OpenPrice[1:(n-1), 1])
```

This should work.

Comment: HI Rosapluech, thank you. I did convert the data using your line, but I have now an issue as the "myData" is not numeric but environment, so the merge do not work: NewDataSet <- data.frame(myData, MP, TR) returns an error: Error in as.data.frame.default(x[[i]], optional = TRUE) : 
  cannot coerce class ""environment"" to a data.frame.

Comment: You already created the data.frame `NewDataSet <- data.frame(myData$AAPL,MP)`. Now use `cbind` to add `TR` to the data.frame. But be aware that the length of `TR` is unequal to the number of rows of your data.frame. So use it for instance like this: `NewDataSet <- cbind(NewDataSet,c(NA,TR))`